# Simplify basic expression

Tags: optimization, computer-algebra-systems

Please, does anyone know which tool can simplify expressions like:

$$a^4 - 4a^3b + 6a^2b^2 - 4ab^3 - a + b^4$$

into:

$$(a - b)^4 - a$$

I tried SymPy, Maxima and W|A without success.

PS: I'm interested in simplifying expressions consisting of addition and subtraction of terms, where each term is a product of some symbols. Another example would be:

$$abc + de + f - ghh + ia - abde + ggg + aabb$$

Comment: I hope "Wolfram Mathematica" will help you

Comment: If neither mathematica nor alpha help you, then you might as well lose hope here.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can say very explicitly what kind of "simplification" you want, I don't think this is feasible.  Given a particular polynomial there are all kinds of ways to group particular sets of terms together, including doing things like inserting pairs of cancelling terms.  The word problem in groups, which is somehow spiritually similar to what you're asking about, is known to be an undecidable problem.

For details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups

Comment: A few of useful metrics would be: minimize the term count or minimize the operator count. The linked article is interesting but I'm not sure it is relevant here: the problem I'm seeking to solve is basically compression.

Comment: The problem is that in order to minimize the number of terms or operations you might need to add and subtract something from the expression, and you can't just brute force it because there are infinitely many things you could conceivably insert that might help. I don't *know*, but my suspicion is that what you're asking for is actually impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but an attempt to undestand your question and Maxima. I had to trick it into thinking that it has a **sum** of expressions (whithout division by c, it doesn't seem to work!) and that it can factor each term of the sum one by one.

(%i68) expr: (b^4-4*a*b^3+6*a^2*b^2-4*a^3*b+a^4)/c-a/c;

(%o68) (b^4-4*a*b^3+6*a^2*b^2-4*a^3*b+a^4)/c-a/c

(%i69) factor(expr);

(%o69) (b^4-4*a*b^3+6*a^2*b^2-4*a^3*b+a^4-a)/c

**(%i70) map(factor, expr);**

**(%o70) (b-a)^4/c-a/c**

Comment: Thanks! This is very interesting but unfortunately it seems to work only for such simple cases...